# Seaborn countplot does not accept both x and y arguments in Python

Tags: python, count, seaborn

I want to plot the frequencies of a variable y by a variable x and to that effect I am using the seaborn.countplot() method.  However I am getting an error message.

For a reproducible example see below:

```
surveys_species_by_plot_sample

    plot_id taxa
0   1   Bird
1   1   Rabbit
2   1   Rodent
3   2   Bird
4   2   Rabbit
5   2   Reptile
6   2   Rodent
7   3   Bird
8   3   Rabbit
9   3   Rodent
```

The intent now is to plot the number of taxa (Birds, Rabbits etc) by plot_id.  I am using the following command:

```
sn.countplot(x = "plot_id", y = "taxa", data = surveys_species_by_plot_sample,
             palette = sn.color_palette(palette = ["SteelBlue" , "Salmon"], n_colors = 4))
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot pass values for both `x` and `y`
```

I do not understand, since the documentation states that both x and y variables can be passed to the function:

> **Parameters:**    x, y, hue : names of variables in data or vector data,
>   optional Inputs for plotting long-form data. See examples for
>   interpretation.
>
> **data :** DataFrame, array, or list of arrays, optional Dataset for
>   plotting. If x and y are absent, this is interpreted as wide-form.
>   Otherwise it is expected to be long-form.

Your advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading examples in the [Documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html),  you can only pass x or y, not both. Stating X or Y changes the orientation of your chart. You might need a different chart type.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use both the x and y in your plot, you can't use countplot, instead you should use sn.barplot :)

sn.barplot(x = "plot_id", y = "taxa", data = surveys_species_by_plot_sample,
palette = sn.color_palette(palette = ["SteelBlue" , "Salmon"], n_colors = 4))